# Why am I getting "Root Element is Missing" error

Tags: xml, json, root

I am having a "Root element is missing" error while trying to call an ASP.NET webservice method from a jquery-Ajax script which specified contentType as application/json. After several checks, I noticed the response type coming from the server is different from what I am expecting.

I'm really stuck here.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function () {
//$('#abc').on('click', function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#abc', function() {
        var parameters;
    $.ajax({
            parameters: { "username": $("#username").serialize(),
            "password": $("#password").serialize() },
            type: "POST",
            data: parameters,
            url: "http://10.142.xxx.74/abc/Service.asmx?op=callgetUserLoginAuthentication",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: WSSucceed,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message);
            }
            //failure: WSFailed
    });
});
```

});

Here is the error displayed from firebug:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Pls advice, I'm stuck.

I cant upload screenshot because of my number of points.

Comment: I don't think the ajax call has a `parameters` argument.

Maybe you should move that out of the call.

Comment: Hi @Steve, the parameters are passed in a single variable (parameters) into the "data" section.
Can you please explain what you mean.

Comment: You have the variable `parameters` INSIDE the literal object as a member variable.  It is probably ignored by jQuery but it certainly doesn't belong there.   The Ajax call takes `url:`, `data:`, `type:`, etc.  It does NOT take `parameters:`.

Comment: @steve thanks for the observation. That helped a whole lot.